# Access a variable throughout the app in Node.js without importing it in all files

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.js. Is there any way I can access a variable throughout in a Node.js app without having to import it in all my app files? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Architecturally, the right way to do it is to define the variable in a module and export access to it.  Then, any module that wants access to it can import that shared module.  I know that isn't what you asked for, but that's the right way to do it.  Just get used to a little more typing in each module that wants access to it.  That's the nodejs way and for a whole bunch of good reasons.

Comment: I know, but if that's the only way then I'll go with that. Thank you.

Comment: It's not the only way.  It's the right way.

Comment: I'll go with it, thanks again.